# Save last record from a history table in parent class with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

The thread title might be a bit misleading, but my problem is this:

I have these three tables, mapped using Hibernate (with annotations):

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment", catalog = "db")
public class Payment implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long paymentId;
    private Set<PaymentStateHistory> paymentStateHistory = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Id
    @Column(name = "payment_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public long getPaymentId() {
        return this.idSolicitud;
    }

    public void setPaymentId(Long paymentId) {
        this.paymentId = paymentId;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "payment")
    public Set<PaymentStateHistory> getPaymentStateHistory() {
        return this.paymentStateHistory;
    }

    public void setPaymentStateHistory(Set<PaymentStateHistory> paymentStateHistory) {
        this.paymentStateHistory = paymentStateHistory;
    }
}
```

---

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment_state_history", catalog = "db")
public class PaymentStateHistory implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long stateHistoryId;
    private PaymentState paymentState;
    private Payment payment;
    private Date stateDate;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "state_history_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getStateHistoryId() {
       return this.stateHistoryId;
    }

    public void setStateHistoryId(Long stateHistoryId) {
       this.stateHistoryId = stateHistoryId;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "state_id", nullable = false)
    public PaymentState getPaymentState() {
       return this.paymentState;
    }

    public void setPaymentState(PaymentState paymentState) {
       this.paymentState = paymentState;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "payment_id", nullable = false)
    public Payment getPayment() {
       return this.payment;
    }

    public void setPayment(Payment payment) {
       this.payment = payment;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "state_date", length = 19)
    public Date getStateDate() {
       return this.stateDate;
    }

    public void setStateDate(Date stateDate) {
       this.stateDate = stateDate;
    }
}
```

---

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name = "payment_state", catalog = "db")
public class PaymentState implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer paymentStateId;
    private String info;
    private Set<PaymentStateHistory> paymentStateHistory = new HashSet<>(0);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "payment_state_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getPaymentStateId() {
        return this.paymentStateId;
    }

    public void setPaymentStateId(Integer paymentStateId) {
        this.paymentStateId = paymentStateId;
    }

    @Column(name = "info", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getInfo() {
        return this.info;
    }

    public void setInfo(String info) {
        this.info = info;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "paymentState")
    public Set<PaymentStateHistory> getPaymentStateHistory() {
        return this.paymentStateHistory;
    }

    public void setPaymentStateHistory(Set<PaymentStateHistory> paymentStateHistory) {
        this.paymentStateHistory = paymentStateHistory;
    }
}
```

Basically, payment_state_history maintains a history of state changes for payment, each with the date that state changed.

The mapping this way is working fine, Payment contains a set of all it's state changes, but I wanted to know if there's a way I can map these relations in a way that I can save the last (newest date) PaymentState in Payment, so I can access it by just loading the required Payment and do something like `payment.getLastState()`.

The payment table also has a "last_state_id" column, relating that row with the last state for that payment in the payment_state_history table (it's updated every time the sate changes). I know I can just map that id, and use that id to find the respective State, but it requeries more queries to the database, making the system slower, so saving a PaymentState object on Payment would be ideal.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new Memeber as below in your Payment Entity

```
private PaymentStateHistory lastPaymentStateHistory;
```

Add the getter and setter as below

```
public void setLastPaymentStateHistory(){
       //code to loop throught paymentStateHistory and set the lastPaymentStateHistory
}
@Transient
public void getLastPaymentStateHistory(){ 
   return this.lastPaymentHistory;
}
```

Then  update the setter of paymentStateHistory as below

```
    public void setPaymentStateHistory(Set<PaymentStateHistory> paymentStateHistory) {
    this.paymentStateHistory = paymentStateHistory;
    setLastPaymentStateHistory();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to map the class with the database in a way that the last state was set when I get the object from he the database, but this might be the solution I'm looking for.

Comment: @if_then_else .. You'r welcome ..please also accept the answer :)